# How to check an UIImageView is out of the visible area of the UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In the UIScrollView, it holds numerous UIImageView objects.

How to check an UIImageView is out of the visible area of the UIScrollView ?

Can an UIImageView observe itself for moving away from the visible area ?

Thanks.

Comment: No , UIImageView can't observe itself moving away.

Answer (score 5):

```
CGRect visibleRect;
visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;

BOOL imageViewIsVisible = CGRectIntersectsRect(visibleRect, imageView.frame);
```

You can observe it in UIScrollViewDelegate's `scrollViewDidScroll:` method